# How to insert record with log_date based on date range it falls under

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements

I have a record and an associate logdate for that record.
I want to insert it into another table based on which date range it falls under from a 3rd table.

For eg:

Record to be inserted into table 1:

```
    Col1 | Col 2 | Col 3 | Log_Date | Table2.ID
```

Table 2:

```
    ID | ColA | ColB | Start_Date | End_Date |
```

If the Log_Date is between Start_Date and End_Date, we insert the record along with the the ID from table 2. I pull in table 2, based on a match on Col2 = ColA and Col3 = ColB.

For example (my explanation is pretty poor, so I hope this makes it clearer):

Table 2:

```
    ID | ColA | ColB | Start_Date | End_Date 

    1  | 123  | 345  | 2018-08-28 | 2018-09-29
    2  | 123  | 345  | 2018-09-29 | NULL
```

In this case, we will join Col 2 = ColA and Col3 = ColB, and get two ID's back.
If Log_Date <= End_Date, I need ID = 1, and if Log_Date > End_Date, I need ID = 2.

More often than not, I will have something similar to above, where I will get a match on 2 rows in table 2, where one End_Date will be NULL.

Any help is appreciated!

P.S. This check will be part of the insert statement, unless there is a better way to do it?

Edit: For further clarity, in the above example let us assume these are the records:

```
    Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Log_Date
    123  | 345  | 456  | 2018-09-01
    123  | 345  | 456  | 2018-09-05
    123  | 345  | 456  | 2018-09-09
    123  | 345  | 456  | 2018-09-15
    123  | 345  | 456  | 2018-10-01
    123  | 345  | 456  | 2018-10-15
```

Then I join these with Table2 on Col1 = ColA and Col2 = ColB

Result:

```
    Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Log_Date   | ID |ColA | ColB | Start_Date | End_Date
    123  | 345  | 456  | 2018-09-01 |  1 | 123 | 345  | 2018-08-28 | 2018-09-29
    123  | 345  | 456  | 2018-09-01 |  2 | 123 | 345  | 2018-09-29 | NULL
    123  | 345  | 456  | 2018-09-05 |  1 | 123 | 345  | 2018-08-28 | 2018-09-29
    123  | 345  | 456  | 2018-09-05 |  2 | 123 | 345  | 2018-09-29 | NULL
    123  | 345  | 456  | 2018-09-09 |  1 | 123 | 345  | 2018-08-28 | 2018-09-29
    123  | 345  | 456  | 2018-09-09 |  2 | 123 | 345  | 2018-09-29 | NULL
    123  | 345  | 456  | 2018-09-15 |  1 | 123 | 345  | 2018-08-28 | 2018-09-29
    123  | 345  | 456  | 2018-09-15 |  2 | 123 | 345  | 2018-09-29 | NULL
    123  | 345  | 456  | 2018-10-01 |  1 | 123 | 345  | 2018-08-28 | 2018-09-29
    123  | 345  | 456  | 2018-10-01 |  2 | 123 | 345  | 2018-09-29 | NULL
    123  | 345  | 456  | 2018-10-15 |  1 | 123 | 345  | 2018-08-28 | 2018-09-29
    123  | 345  | 456  | 2018-10-15 |  2 | 123 | 345  | 2018-09-29 | NULL
```

What I want to insert from this is:

```
    Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Log_Date   | ID |ColA | ColB | Start_Date | End_Date
    123  | 345  | 456  | 2018-09-01 |  1 | 123 | 345  | 2018-08-28 | 2018-09-29
    123  | 345  | 456  | 2018-09-05 |  1 | 123 | 345  | 2018-08-28 | 2018-09-29
    123  | 345  | 456  | 2018-09-09 |  1 | 123 | 345  | 2018-08-28 | 2018-09-29
    123  | 345  | 456  | 2018-09-15 |  1 | 123 | 345  | 2018-08-28 | 2018-09-29
    123  | 345  | 456  | 2018-10-01 |  2 | 123 | 345  | 2018-09-29 | NULL
    123  | 345  | 456  | 2018-10-15 |  2 | 123 | 345  | 2018-09-29 | NULL
```

Comment: Some actual Sample Data and expected results would really help here. I'm afraid what we have isn't clear.

Comment: @Larnu - I added in sample data and desired results!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a stab in the dark, but I *think* this is what you're after. Your logic was incomplete, as it seem like you need to include `Start_Date` too. As a result I don't know if this is the real correct answer:

```
SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3,CONVERT(date,Log_Date) AS Log_Date
INTO dbo.Table1
FROM (VALUES(123,345,456,'20180901'),
            (123,345,456,'20180905'),
            (123,345,456,'20180909'),
            (123,345,456,'20180915'),
            (123,345,456,'20181001'),
            (123,345,456,'20181015'))V(Col1,Col2,Col3,Log_Date);

SELECT ID,ColA,ColB,CONVERT(date,Start_Date) AS Start_Date,CONVERT(date,End_Date) AS End_Date
INTO dbo.Table2
FROM (VALUES(1,123,345,'20180828','20180929'),
            (2,123,345,'20180929',NULL)) V(ID,ColA,ColB,Start_Date,End_Date)
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.Table1 T1
     JOIN dbo.Table2 T2 ON T1.Col1 = T2.ColA
                       AND T1.Col2 = T2.ColB
                       AND ((T1.Log_Date <= T2.End_Date AND T2.ID = 1)
                        OR  (T1.Log_Date >= T2.Start_Date AND (T1.Log_Date > T2.End_Date OR T2.End_Date IS NULL) AND T2.ID = 2));


GO
DROP TABLE dbo.Table1;
DROP TABLE dbo.TAble2;
```